# Sequence to insert an elements in stacks and queues

Tags: data-structures

Does the sequence to insert an element really matters in stacks or queues,i mean to push or to enqueue the data either at start or at the end given we are popping from top in a stack and dequeue from the head in a queue.........Forgive me if this has been already asked.

I hope the question is clear.Thanks in advance.

Comment: A queue (e.g. a line of people waiting for a resource of some sort) is a LIFO (last in first out) structure, because people get added to the back of the queue and leave from the front.  A stack, on the other hand, is a FIFO (first in first out) structure, because the last thing pushed is what gets popped.

Comment: nothing really matters... but changing order of input numbers will change output order

Comment: Well I knew the theoretical explanations......but the problrm occured while implementing it anyway thanks for your answers.@Tim Biegeleisen & @Ilya Bursov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzfB2.png)

A stack is a basic data structure that can be logically thought as linear structure represented by a real physical stack or pile, a structure where insertion and deletion of items takes place at one end called top of the stack. The basic concept can be illustrated by thinking of your data set as a stack of plates or books where you can only take the top item off the stack in order to remove things from it. So yeah this is a data structures not a open source project, sequence matters.

Same goes for Queue